# How to solve limits with $\tan$

Tags: calculus, limits

With this $\tan 2x$ on top, I can't really think of any ways to solve it.

$$
\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan 2x}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}
$$

So is it solvable and how?

What I have came up so far:

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan 2x}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}} \\
=\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan 2x}{4x-2\pi}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Have you tried L'Hopital's Rule

Comment: It's not true that $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan 2x}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}} =\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan 2x}{4x-2\pi}$.  It is true that $\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan 2x}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}} =\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{4\tan 2x}{4x-2\pi}$.  If you multiply the denominator by something, you have to multiply the numerator by the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y=x-\frac{\pi}2$. Then $2x=2y+\pi$

$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan 2x}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\tan(2y+\pi)}y=\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\tan 2y}y=2\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\tan 2y}{2y}\;.$$

That’s a limit that you should either know or be able to calculate fairly easily.

(Of course you can also use l’Hospital’s rule, which works easily on this limit.)

Comment: @Derek: My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Use L'Hôpital's rule.
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\tan 2x}{x-\frac{\pi}{2}}
&= \lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} 2\sec^2 2x \\
&= 2
\end{align}